# Create a new row in the results set for each newline character in an entered string

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to be able to convert a comma separated value string to a table. So far, I've been able to create the table off of the entered string, but I'm also trying to have a new row added for each newline. I'm thinking this can be done by looping through the string and splitting at each newline (can't use `STRING_SPLIT()` unfortunately), then adding a union to the dynamic SELECT for each. However, this sounds like it may be the least efficient method of going about this.

This is the code I have so far:

```
DECLARE @ps_String varchar(max),
        @ps_Delimiter char(1),
        @ls_XML xml,
        @ln_Count INT,
        @ls_SQL VARCHAR(MAX) = ''

SELECT @ps_String = 'ab,cd,ef,gh,ij,
kl, mn, op, qr,st',
       @ps_Delimiter = ','

SET @ls_SQL = '
DECLARE @ls_XML XML
SELECT @ls_XML = CONVERT(xml,'' <root> <myvalue>'' +
REPLACE('''+@ps_String+''','''+@ps_Delimiter+''',''</myvalue> <myvalue>'') + ''</myvalue>   </root> '')
SELECT DISTINCT'

SET @ln_Count = 1
WHILE (@ln_Count <= LEN(@ps_String) - LEN(REPLACE(@ps_String, @ps_Delimiter, '')) + 1 ) BEGIN
    SET @ls_SQL = @ls_SQL + '
    T.c.value(''(/root/myvalue)['+CONVERT(VARCHAR, @ln_Count)+']'',''VARCHAR(20)''),'
    SET @ln_Count = @ln_Count + 1
END

SET @ls_SQL = LEFT(@ls_SQL, LEN(@ls_SQL) - 1)

SET @ls_SQL = @ls_SQL + '
FROM @ls_XML.nodes(''/root/myvalue'') T(c)'

PRINT @ls_SQL
--EXEC(@ls_SQL)
```

SQL Server 2014

Comment: *"I'm trying to be able to convert a comma separated value string to a table"* The idea is identical, just define the delimiter as `CHAR(10)` instead of a comma (`) and remove the `CHAR(13)` characters, or replace `CHAR(10)` with `,` (and again remove `CHAR(13)` characters).

Comment: Note, however, a `WHILE` is a terrible way to split the data. SQL Server is a set based language and you should be using set based solutions. I personally recommend a set based solution, such as an true set-based XML splitter, [`DelimitedSplit8K_LEAD`](https://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/reaping-the-benefits-of-the-window-functions-in-t-sql-2), or even a CLR function.

Comment: @Larnu I'm still pretty new to coding in SQL so I think most of that article went over my head, but that was a great read nonetheless! Thank you for linking that!

Comment: Glad you took the time to read it. I appreciate it isn't entry level, but it's so refreshing to hear someone taking the time to learn, and do further reading, on this site; you forget that some do exist! ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The approach below would be one way of retrieving any string split information required for a dynamic SQL statement construction. It consists of 2 recursive common table expressions to first split the rows en then the columns.

[Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2014&fiddle=93c3152ee4551fcc390fada9f6190649) in case you prefer to see it in action.

```
declare @data nvarchar(100) = N'ab,cd,ef,gh,ij,
kl, mn, op, qr,st';

declare @rowDelimiter nvarchar(1) = char(10);
declare @colDelimiter nvarchar(1) = ',';

with cte_rows as
(
  select 1 as RowNum,
         @data as Data,
         1 as Starts,
         charindex(@rowDelimiter, @data) as Pos
    union all
  select cr.RowNum + 1,
         cr.Data,
         cr.Pos+1,
         charindex(@rowDelimiter, cr.Data, cr.Pos+1)
  from cte_rows cr
  where cr.Pos > 0
),
cte_cols as
(
  select cr.RowNum,
         1 as ColNum,
         substring(cr.data, cr.Starts, case when cr.Pos > 0 then cr.Pos-cr.Starts else len(cr.data) end) as RowData,
         1 as Starts,
         charindex(@colDelimiter,  substring(cr.data, cr.Starts, case when cr.Pos > 0 then cr.Pos-cr.Starts else len(cr.data) end)) as Pos
  from cte_rows cr
    union all
  select cc.RowNum,
         cc.ColNum + 1,
         cc.RowData,
         cc.Pos+1,
         charindex(@colDelimiter, cc.RowData, cc.Pos+1)
  from cte_cols cc
  where cc.Pos > 0
)
select cc.RowNum,
       cc.ColNum,
       rtrim(ltrim(substring(cc.RowData, cc.Starts, case when cc.Pos>0 then cc.Pos-cc.Starts else len(cc.RowData) end))) as ColVal
from cte_cols cc
order by cc.RowNum, cc.ColNum;
```

Result:

```
RowNum ColNum ColVal
------ ------ ------
1      1      ab
1      2      cd
1      3      ef
1      4      gh
1      5      ij
1      6      
2      1      kl
2      2      mn
2      3      op
2      4      qr
2      5      st
```

There are 6 columns for row 1 versus 5 columns for row 2 because row 1 has a trailing comma and row 2 does not. Either filter this dataset on `ColVal <> ''` or remove the trailing comma after the substring selection in `cte_cols` (`RowData`).

Adding a *fixed* pivot after the previous query to preview potential output after creating a dynamic SQL statement:

```
declare @data nvarchar(100) = N'ab,cd,ef,gh,ij,
kl, mn, op, qr,st';

declare @rowDelimiter nvarchar(1) = char(10);
declare @colDelimiter nvarchar(1) = ',';

-- split rows + columns and pivot
with cte_rows as
(
  select 1 as RowNum,
         @data as Data,
         1 as Starts,
         charindex(@rowDelimiter, @data) as Pos
    union all
  select cr.RowNum + 1,
         cr.Data,
         cr.Pos+1,
         charindex(@rowDelimiter, cr.Data, cr.Pos+1)
  from cte_rows cr
  where cr.Pos > 0
),
cte_cols as
(
  select cr.RowNum,
         1 as ColNum,
         substring(cr.data, cr.Starts, case when cr.Pos > 0 then cr.Pos-cr.Starts else len(cr.data) end) as RowData,
         1 as Starts,
         charindex(@colDelimiter,  substring(cr.data, cr.Starts, case when cr.Pos > 0 then cr.Pos-cr.Starts else len(cr.data) end)) as Pos
  from cte_rows cr
    union all
  select cc.RowNum,
         cc.ColNum + 1,
         cc.RowData,
         cc.Pos+1,
         charindex(@colDelimiter, cc.RowData, cc.Pos+1)
  from cte_cols cc
  where cc.Pos > 0
),
cte_values as
(
  select cc.RowNum,
         cc.ColNum,
         rtrim(ltrim(substring(cc.RowData, cc.Starts, case when cc.Pos>0 then cc.Pos-cc.Starts else len(cc.RowData) end))) as ColVal
  from cte_cols cc
)
select p.RowNum,
       p.[1] as Col1,
       p.[2] as Col2,
       p.[3] as Col3,
       p.[4] as Col4,
       p.[5] as Col5,
       p.[6] as Col6
from cte_values cv
pivot (max(cv.ColVal) for cv.ColNum in ([1], [2], [3], [4], [5], [6])) p
order by p.RowNum;
```

This gives:

```
RowNum Col1    Col2    Col3    Col4    Col5    Col6
------ ------- ------- ------- ------- ------- -------
1      ab      cd      ef      gh      ij      
2      kl      mn      op      qr      st      null
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a definite hack you might try:

```
DECLARE @ps_String VARCHAR(MAX) = 'ab,cd,ef,gh,ij,
kl, mn, op, qr,st';

/* Clean-up and divide the provided string into rows based on CR/LF */
SET @ps_String = (
    SELECT 
        REPLACE ( cleanString, ',', '</val><val>' ) AS myXml
    FROM (
            SELECT '<rows><row><val>' + REPLACE ( REPLACE ( @ps_String, CHAR(13), '' ), CHAR(10), '</val></row><row><val>' ) + '</val></row></rows>' AS rws
    ) AS getRows
    CROSS APPLY ( SELECT REPLACE ( getRows.rws, ',<', '<' ) AS cleanString ) AS stripTrailingComma
);

/* Add a unique row id to each row */
DECLARE @id INT = 0;
WHILE CHARINDEX ( '<row>', @ps_String ) > 0 
BEGIN
    SET @id = @id + 1;
    SET @ps_String = STUFF ( @ps_String, CHARINDEX ( '<row>', @ps_String ) + 4, 0, FORMATMESSAGE ( ' id="%i"', @id ) ); 
END

/* Show results */
SELECT
    r.v.value( '../@id', 'INT' ) AS row_id,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( PARTITION BY r.v.value( '../@id', 'INT' ) ORDER BY r.v.value( '../@id', 'INT' ) ) AS val_id,
    LTRIM( RTRIM( r.v.value( '.', 'VARCHAR(255)' ) ) ) AS val
FROM (
    SELECT CAST ( @ps_String AS XML ) AS rws
) AS myXml
CROSS APPLY rws.nodes( '//rows/row/val' ) r(v);
```

Returns

```
+--------+--------+-----+
| row_id | val_id | val |
+--------+--------+-----+
|      1 |      1 | ab  |
|      1 |      2 | cd  |
|      1 |      3 | ef  |
|      1 |      4 | gh  |
|      1 |      5 | ij  |
|      2 |      1 | kl  |
|      2 |      2 | mn  |
|      2 |      3 | op  |
|      2 |      4 | qr  |
|      2 |      5 | st  |
+--------+--------+-----+
```